# Why am I getting huge difference in my R^2 after cross validation?

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am doing cross validation for my regressor, I have a small dataset, around 100 datapoints. When I do cross validation, I get huge difference in R^2 value (R^2 varies from 0.159 to 0.88), why is that? From what I understand, my dataset is small and probably for some kfolds, the training datasets are not capturing all the features, that's why this lead to bad generalization when testing the model and very low R^2? Is my interpretation correct? What can I do to get around this (extending the datapoints is not an option currently)?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

crossvalidation_poly = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

#for train_index, test_index in crossvalidation_poly.split(X_normalized):


for i in range(1,11):
    poly_cross_validation = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    X_current = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    model = lin_regressor.fit(X_current, y_for_normalized)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X_current,y_for_normalized, scoring='r2', cv=crossvalidation_poly,
 n_jobs=1)
    

    print("\n\nDegree-"+str(i)+" polynomial: R^2 for every fold: " + str(np.abs(scores)))
          
          #+" training: " + str(np.abs(train_index))+" \ntesting: " + str(np.abs(test_index)))

    print('\033[1m'+"Degree-"+str(i)+'\033[1m'+"polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(scores))) + '\033[0m'+ ", STD: " + str(np.std(scores)))


    Degree-1 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.4211881  0.1594833  0.330413   0.33658905 0.85793866 0.46608985
 0.83313018 0.01226627 0.12584021 0.88849593]
Degree-1polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.4431434552827308, STD: 0.41377024559244985
```

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @ale_C 100 rows/data points.

Comment: Try reducing n_splits to 3, It should give you more consistent results

Comment: @ale_C Thank you. I just want to understand, why my R^2 values are inconsistent? Just for my knowledge. Also, would you please tell me based on what you've chosen  n_splits to be=3? Like is there a general rule or something?

Comment: 1) Because you are increasing the points in validation set, so you are "using less data" to train the model. 2) Experience and heuristic 3)you can also don't use cross validation. Simply create you test set with replacement sampling and use that for evaluating 
your models

Comment: @ale_C Thanks a bunch. One more question (sorry), as you've noticed I am using cross validation for my entire dataset, I found examples online on applying cross validation only on the training and testing datasets (after splitting). I guess what I am doing is better because it uses the whole dataset for training and testing and the result generalizes better in my case, may I get your thoughts on this? or shall I apply cross validation on the training and testing datasets, not on the entire dataset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247186/discussion-between-ale-c-and-z47).

Comment: @ale_C "1) Because you are increasing the points in validation set, so you are "using less data" to train the model." I am not using any validation set for now, just raining and testing. But increasing the k from 3 to 10 results in higher number of training data!